# stacking order without z-index

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

I am facing the following problem : My `.line div` comes above the `.list div` and I do not understand why. I defined no new stacking context through `z-index` so shouldn't stacking order only be defined by the order of appearance in HTML? Or is there something else defining a new stacking context in my case that I don't see?

Thanks a bunch

```css
body {
    font-family:helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.line {
    background-color:red;
    height: 150px;
    width:1px;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    left: 57px;
    top:20px;
}

.list {
    list-style-type:none;
    display: inline-block;    
}

.written {
    width:200px;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    
}

.dot {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float:left;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class=line>
        </div>
        <ul class=list>
            <li>
                <div class=dot>
                </div>
                <p class=written>First thing</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class=dot>
                </div>
                <p class=written>Second thing</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class=dot>
                </div>
                <p class=written>Third thing</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want to set vertical line behind the circle?

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: I think Oleg is more after why the line ends up in front of the dots.

Comment: Yes I want the vertical line to be behind the dots, but more than just a workaround I would really like to understand why it keeps coming to the front because I don't see the rule that has this effect :)

Answer (score 2):

From [the CSS 2 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html#q23.0).

> Step 4: For all its in-flow, non-positioned, block-level descendants in tree order
>
> Step 8: All positioned descendants with 'z-index: auto' or 'z-index: 0', in tree order.

`<ul class=list>` is painted at step 4. `<div class=line>` is painted at step 8. i.e. on top.

Comment: Thanks a lot, looks pretty complete but that's a bit chinese to me. Is it because my list is not positioned? If I add position:relative; it keeps doing the same so that couldn't be it right? Is it because my <ul> it is a block-level element? If yes shouldn't putting it within a <div> solve the problem (which it doesn't when I try)?

Answer (score 0):

Your `<div class=line>` comes above your `<ul class=list>` because of its `position:relative;` property. If you add the same to your `.list` selector, your `<ul class=list>` will be on top! View example here : https://jsfiddle.net/Lsq0tc12/

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Yeah no it doesn't

Comment: Yeah it does. Add a `background-color:black;` to your `.list` class and you'll see it hides the red line, therefore it is above / on top. See here : https://jsfiddle.net/Lsq0tc12/1/

Comment: Ooh now I get it, thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome, and also, welcome to Stack Overflow. =) If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```css
body {
    font-family:helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.line {
    background-color:red;
    height: 150px;
    width:1px;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    left: 57px;
    top:20px;
}

.list {
    list-style-type:none;
    display: inline-block;    
}

.written {
    width:200px;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    
}

.dot {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float:left;
    margin: 5px;
}

.list > li {
  margin-left: -56px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>                
        <div class=line>
          <ul class=list>
            <li>
                <div class=dot>
                </div>
                <p class=written>First thing</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class=dot>
                </div>
                <p class=written>Second thing</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class=dot>
                </div>
                <p class=written>Third thing</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

i hope this help you.
thanks.

Comment: Hi mate, thanks but it does not work